# How to pass a String array value from one activity to another Activity in android?

Tags: android

I am having two activities in my application. I want to pass tha array of String from one activity to another.. How to pass this values from activity to activity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can consider using [Intent.getStringArrayExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

In the first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string-array", stringArray);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second one:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String [] stringArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
```

Comment: in that second one how to declare the intent. please sent me the format

Answer (score 3):

Here's some reading: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#overview_accessdata go to section 2.1.

Also, [How to pass ArrayList using putStringArrayListExtra()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030115/how-to-pass-arraylist-using-putstringarraylistextra) should explain something similar.

Answer (score 2):

just serialize it and set it in the extras of the intent (of activity) you wanna open.

You will receive it in the onCreate() of that activity.
Convert it to array again.

Comment: consider using @kgiannakakis 's sample. Its more straight forward than what I told. I got Intent.getStringArrayExtra skipped from my mind.

Answer (score 2):

In Activity One, write this code to create an array and pass it to another activity:

```
String[] array1={"asd","fgh","dcf","dg","ere","dsf"};
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
i.putExtra("key",array1);
startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity, write this to retrieve your array

```
String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationcontext, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mStringArray", mystringArray);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In the New activity in `onCreate` event

```
String[] mystringArray = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("mStringArray");
```

If you want to send more data with different data types you should use ***BUNDLE.***

Comment: Where do you declare the intent in the receiving activity?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, make that variable static & make one public static method in that class like

```
public static getArray() 
{ 
        return array; 
}
```

Now access this method from another activity, where you want to access it.

Comment: I wud say its not a good coding practice to have your data variables static and giving the access to modify them from anywhere the app. Best way is to pass it through the bundles in the intent. Try to do it as in the ans from @kgiannakakis, as its not about the ease but about the stability and robustness in the code makes you a good programmer.