# How to pass array list between activities

Tags: android, arrays, json, arraylist

I have this array list and i parsing list item from json like this ,

```
    List<String> imageUrls;

    imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey);

    for (int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
         String imageList = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString(labelKey).toString();
         imageUrls.add(imageList);
     }
    appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);
```

then i try to do this in another activity ,

```
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", appShowModule.getAllimage());
```

but "appShowModule.getAllimage()" is error ! and how i can received it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass ArrayList using putStringArrayListExtra()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030115/how-to-pass-arraylist-using-putstringarraylistextra)

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: You always need to be specific about your errors. What does `getAllimage()` return? If it returns a generic `List`, you'll need to cast it to `ArrayList<String>` to use it there - `(ArrayList<String>) appShowModule.getAllimage()`. The linked duplicate has examples of how to retrieve it in the next `Activity`.

Comment: public List<String> getAllimageurl() {
        return Allimageurl;
    }

Comment: in the module i have this 

private List<String> Allimage = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getAllimage() { return Allimage;}
    public void setAllimage(List<String> allimage) { Allimage = allimage; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Your Array list to intent from which you are calling another activity

```
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", yourarraylist);
 startActivity(intent);
```

To get the array list in activity.

```
ArrayList list= new ArrayList();
list=  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in your class.

Check this best [link](https://www.amedeobaragiola.me/blog/2014/04/25/how-to-pass-customobjectarraylist-from-one-activity-to-another-using-parcelable/) for easy understanding.

Thanks

Comment: i try it its not working i wont another solution thank you

Comment: yes, i also face some problem in starting, you can use the another link i specified. But take some time for it. If problem persists then go for serialization or direct access by making it static

Comment: Do you really need to implemet Parcelable in this case? As it is  a List of plain String @Androider

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in `Intent`:

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, CharSequence[] value)
```

Comment: then ? what do in the method ? i wont to passing this array to more than one activity ! how can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

change List imageUrls to ArrayList imageUrls and 
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",imageUrls);

Comment: ok i do it but this cannot be applied 

                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",appShowModule.getAllimage());

Comment: please tell me appShowModule.getAllimage() what it will return.

Answer (score 0):

Send your list like this

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YourDesiredActiity.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayListToSend",imageUrls);
    startActivity(i);
```

And then in your desired activity  , receive the list like this

```
   ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        urlList.addAll(extras.getStringArrayList("arrayListToSend"));
    }
```

Then you can get your desired arrayList in "`urlList`"

Comment: Declare you imageUrls   variable like this  ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>(); and then follow my answer hope it will work